# MySQL Determine if user has logged in within X days

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

I am creating a sql query that determines if the user has been a member for one year and if so than sends an email. My logic tells me I should also ensure that they have been active within that past year of service. Here is my sql query:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(date_created,'%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 365 DAY = CURRENT_DATE() AND FROM_UNIXTIME(last_login,'%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 365 DAY >= CURRENT_DATE()`

My assumption is that if the last_login + 365 day is greater than or equal to the current date, that means they've logged in within the 365 day.

Last Login is a TIMESTAMP. Is that a correct SQL Query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to know if it's a valid query is to test it, and the only way to test it is to create data that straddles the boundary conditions.

Do make a point to see what happens on February 29th, 2014 as well, or to people who last logged in on that day.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is currently returning the set of users who were created precisely a year ago and who logged in since. Don't you want the users who were created *up to* a year ago and who logged in? i.e. `>= CURRENT_DATE()` instead of `= CURRENT_DATE()`.